# utilizar el contenido de una celda como Hyperlink en un boton

Tags: excel, vba

tengo el Path completo en una celda (dependiendo del fichero que este en una carpeta definida esa celda recoge y concatena el full path), lo quiero utilizar como hyperlink utilizando un botón, para que cuando le doy al botón me abra el fichero actualmente en la carpeta y por lo tanto definido en mi celda.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor haz el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Debes mostrar lo que has intentado, tratando de ofrecer un [mcve].

Comment: Algo tipo `ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink ActiveCell.Value` debería servirte, siempre y cuando `ActiveCell.Value` tenga una ruta válida

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfectamente. añadido la activacion de la celda y marcha, tengo el boton en la hoja "Dashboard" y el path en la hoja "Calculo" en la celda A6.                                                                                                        
       Sub Hyper()

  
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet
    Dim dstSht As Worksheet
    Set srcSht = Sheets("Calculo")
    Set dstSht = Sheets("Dashboard")
    srcSht.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A6").Select
    
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink ActiveCell.Value
    
    dstSht.Activate

End Sub